# User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email) in ASP.NET MVC Core 6 using VS 2022 returns Null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I'm using ASP.NET 6 MVC Core using VS 2022 community edition. `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` is working fine but the `ClaimTypes.Email` returning null.

```
string userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); working fine
string userEmailAddress = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email); //returning Null.
```

After a successful transaction from Paypal, I am passing id, email and item details for completing the order. Here is the issue Email is returning null, I think it's a problem in .NET 6.0 and its working fine with the same code in .NET 5.0 (VS 2019) but returning Null in Vs2022

[image: After a successful transaction from Paypal, I am passing id, email and item details for completing the order. Here is the issue Email is returning Null, I think it's a problem in .NET 6.0 and its working fine with the same code in .NET 5.0 (VS 2019) but returning Null in Vs2022]

Comment: How and when do you set that claim and which value do you expect to come out of it?

Comment: Basically I am doing PayPall Order and want to retrieve specific Email of Logged In User

Comment: At some point that claim has to be set, in order to be retrieved. When do you set this claim? Could you add some prose to your question with a bit more context? What do you do? How do you do it? What goes wrong what is the expected outcome. If possible with a reproducible example for us.

Comment: Sir i have just edit , basically after successful transaction from Paypal i am passing id,email with item details but here is the issue  email is returning null, 
in Vs 2019 dot net 5 same code is working fine but i am getting trouble in vs 2022 dot net 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `User.Claims` to see what claims are available, and if there is a claim with type `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/emailaddress`, then you should expect `User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)` returns the value, otherwise claim is missing or check is there is any claim with the `Email` type.

[image]

Comment: something like this 
public const string Email = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress";

Comment: Is this new on .net6? In .net5 it worked correctly only with "email". The nuget package identity-model also use claim names (in JwtClaimTypes.Email) without namespaces.